# How to run my Go code in Android?

Tags: android, linux, go

How can i run this Go code in my Android? (in Fedora 15 its working).

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to compile it for ARM, and thankfully it is very easy with Go's compilers:

```
$ 5g main.go && 5l main.5
```

The executive binary (5.out) will be runnable on Android. Just copy it there and run with shell. More info [here](http://nf.id.au/go-under-android).

Comment: What libraries are available on Android ? Is the go standard API covered ?

Comment: Yes, Go links libraries statically, and that means you can even use third-party libraries in your Go program. Everything is bundled with your executable binary. I'm not sure about what strange cases might happen in the mobile environment, but generally everything should work.

Comment: Never tried, but I don't think so. Android does not support GTK. And GoGL developer only declares Linux support for now.

Answer (score 3):

With Go 1.0, the compilers changed from separate compiler executables for different target architectures to a single compiler executable. Thus, the process of compiling for ARM is slightly different from Go 1.0 on:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0
GOOS=linux
GOARCH=arm
go build main.go
```

The (environment) variables GOOS and GOARCH have to be set to match the android environment, which is a linux OS and an ARM hardware architecture. Then you can use `go build` as you would compile for any other platform (which will then act according to the set variables).

Comment: why so many arguments? Can Go not use simple `make` or `python` like run compile/build method?

Comment: ... Cgo = false, SO = linux (android use linus) architecture = arm (hardware of android)

Comment: Is disabling CGO a necessity?

Comment: As your answer was really … short, but still correct, I expanded it with actual sentences and background information. So it’s actually a pleasure to read and one can learn from. I hope that was alright with you.

Comment: My Go installation complains: 
`go build runtime: exec: "/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/5g": stat /usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/5g: no such file or directory`